# Too much memory allocated by curl (memory cached by libcurl)

Tags: c, memory, libcurl

We are using LibCurl for our SetTop Box applications. It is used in multi-threaded environment and we may open multiple curl handles at the same time but we close it as soon as the download is done.

It seems like while opening the curl handle (no matter how much we download), curl allocates some memory which increases as the number of curl handle increases (I tested a scenario with 100 threads --- where about 30Mb of memory is allocated in advance). (as soon as we call curl_easy_init()---there is jump in the memory which is not de-allocated after the handle is destroyed)

In our applications, For example: one curl handle may be just used to see if the server is up or not --- but even this is costing us memory.

Memory is very critical in our scenario. So, we do not want curl to cache that much of memory in advance.

Is there any suggestions that can help us to reduce the memory cached by curl?

Comment: you've tagged this with 3 languages... which one is it?

Comment: did you look at curl_easy_cleanup(curl);?

Comment: yes, we are cleaning the curl handle after each usage.

Comment: --- but we have like 8 curl handles in different threads that are open until the application is shut down...

Answer (score 0):

http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_init.html

See the described problem in a multithreaded case. 
Quote:

This function must be the first function to call, and it returns a CURL easy handle that you must use as input to other easy-functions. curl_easy_init initializes curl and this call MUST have a corresponding call to curl_easy_cleanup(3) when the operation is complete.

If you did not already call curl_global_init(3), curl_easy_init(3) does it automatically. This may be lethal in multi-threaded cases, since curl_global_init(3) is not thread-safe, and it may result in resource problems because there is no corresponding cleanup.

You are strongly advised to not allow this automatic behaviour, by calling curl_global_init(3) yourself properly. See the description in libcurl(3) of global environment requirements for details of how to use this function.

Comment: we are calling curl_global_init() with option CURL_GLOBAL_NOTHING at the start of the module and curl_global_cleanup () at the end.